# Custom gitea image doesn't find user with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ldap, bitnami, gitea

I'm developing a Docker infrastructure with Ansible and Docker Compose and I have a problem with my custom image of Gitea.
I want to use a custom image because I need to implement authentication via LDAP.
The error that i get inside the container log is:

```
sudo: unknown user: gitea
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

This is my configuration:

app.ini (of Gitea)

```
[DEFAULT]
RUN_USER = git
RUN_MODE = prod

...

[database]
PATH = /data/gitea/gitea.db
DB_TYPE = postgres
HOST = db:5432
NAME = gitea
USER = gitea
PASSWD = gitea
LOG_SQL = false

...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gitea/gitea:1.16.8
RUN apk add sudo
RUN chmod 777 /home
COPY entrypoint /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
COPY gitea-cli.sh /usr/bin/gitea-cli.sh
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
```

entrypoint

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo 'Started entrypoint'
while ! nc -z $GITEA__database__HOST; do sleep 1; done;
echo 'Starting operations'
gitea-cli.sh migrate
>- gitea-cli.sh admin auth add-ldap --name ansible-ldap --host 127.0.0.1 --port 1389 --security-protocol unencrypted --user-search-base dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it --admin-filter "(objectClass=giteaAdmin)" --user-filter "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=%s))" --username-attribute uid --firstname-attribute givenName --surname-attribute surname --email-attribute mail --bind-dn cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it --bind-password admin --allow-deactivate-all
echo 'Ending entrypoint'
```

gitea-cli.sh

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Started gitea-cli'
USER=git HOME=/home/gitea GITEA_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/gitea sudo -E -u git gitea --config /data/gitea/conf/app.ini "$@"
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: gitea
      POSTGRES_USER: gitea
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gitea
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - vcc

  openldap:
    image: bitnami/openldap:2.5
    ports:
      - 1389:1389
      - 1636:1636
    environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: "true"
      LDAP_LOGLEVEL: 4
      LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      LDAP_ROOT: dc=ldap,dc=vcc,dc=unige,dc=it
      LDAP_CUSTOM_LDIF_DIR: /bitnami/openldap/backup
      LDAP_CUSTOM_SCHEMA_FILE: /bitnami/openldap/schema/schema.ldif
    volumes:
      - /data/openldap/:/bitnami/openldap
    networks:
      - vcc

  gitea:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/custom_gitea:51
    restart: always
    hostname: git.localdomain
    build: /data/gitea/custom
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 222:22
    environment:
      USER: git
      USER_UID: 1000
      USER_GID: 1000
      GITEA__database__DB_TYPE: postgres
      GITEA__database__HOST: db:5432
      GITEA__database__NAME: gitea
      GITEA__database__USER: gitea
      GITEA__database__PASSWD: gitea
      GITEA__security__INSTALL_LOCK: "true"
      GITEA__security__SECRET_KEY: XQolFkmSxJWhxkZrkrGbPDbVrEwiZshnzPOY
    volumes:
      - /data/gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /data/gitea/app.ini:/data/gitea/conf/app.ini
    # deploy:
    #   mode: global
    depends_on:
      - db
      - openldap
      - openldap_admin
    networks:
      - vcc
```

Comment: **gitea** user don't exist in the image. Replace gitea by git in the gitea service of the dockerfile and the app.ini **OR** add `RUN adduser -h /data/gitea -D -s /bin/bash gitea` in the docker and change it's **USER_UID** and **USER_GUI** env with 1001 (1000 is git)

Comment: @DrClaw thank you, that solved the error, but now gitea is in a loop and continue to restart itself, do you know why? I have updated the question with the changes that you have suggested.

Comment: Can you send in a gist the output of `docker compose logs gitea`. Without i can't know.

Comment: maybe replace **/home/gitea** by **/data/git**  in gitea-cli.sh (its home folder) "git:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/data/git:/bin/bash"

Comment: @DrClaw the logs say:  "settings saved to /data/gitea/conf/app.ini" and right after that  "error saving to custom config:  open /data/gitea/conf/app.ini permission denied"

Comment: @DrClaw and this makes the service into a bootloop, do you know why? Thank you

Comment: Remplace every "/data/gitea" by "/data/git"

Comment: @DrClaw I have replaced them but now it says "Unable to find configuration file /data/git/conf/app.ini"

Comment: Previous comment is bad. Before `gitea-cli.sh migrate` in entrypoint trye `chown -R 1000:1000 /data/gitea/conf`

Comment: @DrClaw that finally worked, unfortunately I got another error: "failed to run app with [ usr/bin/local/ gitea --config /data/gitea/conf/app.ini admin auth add-ldap etc...]: login source already exists [name: ansible-ldap]". I think that I need to remove the previous ansible-ldap before installing the new one, right?

Comment: I think yes and delete also the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User **gitea** simply don't exist in the image.

```bash
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh gitea/gitea:1.16.8
/ # grep gitea /etc/shadow
/ # grep gitea /etc/passwd
/ #
```

The default user is git:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh gitea/gitea:1.16.8
/ # tail -1 /etc/passwd
git:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/data/git:/bin/bash
/ #
```

There is two solutions:

- add gitea user (not recommended)
- use the default user provide by the image (git).

#### Adding gitea user

Just add `adduser` in your Dockerfile and it should work:

```
FROM gitea/gitea:1.16.8
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/bash gitea   # <---- HERE
RUN apk add sudo
COPY entrypoint /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
COPY gitea-cli.sh /usr/bin/gitea-cli.sh
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/custom_entrypoint
```

You'll also have to change the **USER_UID** and **USER_GID** with 1001 (user 1000 is git)

#### Using default user

Just replace user **gitea** with **git** in the gitea service of the dockerfile and in the app.ini .

After that, if you have error like:

```
error saving to custom config: open /data/gitea/conf/app.ini permission denied
```

You have to add `chown -R 1000:1000 /data/gitea/conf` before **gitea-cli.sh migrate** in entrypoint.

Because you share volume between the host and the container, this will work **only** if you host user have UID 1000. If not you will have to modify the gitea service in the docker-compose.yml.

Example with an user id of 1002:

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
  gitea:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5000/custom_gitea:51
    restart: always
    [...]
    environment:
      USER: git
      USER_UID: 1002
      USER_GID: 1002
    [...]
    user: 1002:1002 # <----- HERE
```

and before the ENTRYPOINT in the dockerfile:

```
USER git
ENTRYPOINT ....
```